# How to present html tags in radio label text with woocommerce_form_field()?

Tags: php, html, arrays, woocommerce, selector

I use following array and need to assign a *css class selector* to the *first value of array*, but output displays HTML markup too!

```php
woocommerce_form_field(
    $field_id, 
    array(
        'type'          => 'radio',
        'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
        'options'       => array(
            'alert' => ' <p class="alert">Please allow 2-5 business days for delivery after order processing.</p> ',
            jdate(('d F Y'), $twoDaysAfterTomorrow ) => jdate((' l ، j F Y  '), $twoDaysAfterTomorrow ),
        )
    )
);
```

However this is showing unrendered radio label text like:

```
<p class="alert">Please allow 2-5 business days for delivery after order processing.</p>
```

How is it possible to use HTML tags within field label text and have the markup rendered on the webpage?

Comment: Why are you needlessly wrapping the first argument of `jdate()` in parentheses?

Comment: @mickmackusa it is pre-defined function : `jdate( $format , $timestamp , $none , $time_zone , $tr_num );` and I use it to convert date to a native form.

Comment: `'d F Y'` is sensible.  `('d F Y')` is needless code bloat.

Comment: @mickmackusa Yup but does it help to omit <p></p> from code output?

Answer (score 0):

You are fighting again the native behavior of the code.

See https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-template-functions.html#source-view.2668

```
esc_html( $option_text );
```

This means that no matter what string you pass into that radio markup building function, the label's text will be html encode to keep your site safe.

If you need to find a solution, then perhaps you could try to override/overwrite that function (not recommended), or write a new function that delivers the desired output without html encoding the text, or just manually create the desired output if this is a solitary use case.

I do not use WP, so I will not be providing a ready-made solution.  I suspect that you will be able to engineer your own solution based on the linked source code.

Answer (score -1):

Use `\"` for inner quotes. https://3v4l.org/DkHT1

Comment: It does not work. Still output of code is similar to source and I see this line as output : <p class=\"alert\">Please allow 2-5 business days for delivery after order processing.</p>

Comment: You use an arrow for a named array, after the first comma, you already have a regular array, not named. options => array(key=>value, wtf=>value, VALUE)